# Plotting Data from XML that has Timestamps on the X-axis

Tags: xml, r

I got help parsing the following XML file on this site:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
    <Company >
   <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.01</timeStamp>
    <Price>  25.02</Price>
   </shareprice>

   <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.02</timeStamp>
    <Price>  15</Price>
   </shareprice>



   <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.025</timeStamp>
    <Price>  15.02</Price>
    </shareprice>



    <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.031</timeStamp>
    <Price>  18.25</Price>
</shareprice>



  <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.039</timeStamp>
    <Price>  18.54</Price>
  </shareprice>



   <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:00.050</timeStamp>
    <Price> 16.52</Price>
  </shareprice>


    <shareprice>
    <timeStamp> 12:00:01.01</timeStamp>
    <Price>  17.50</Price>
    </shareprice>
</Company>
```

I am using the following code in R to try and plot the data to get the share price on the Y axis and the timestamp on the x axis:

```
library (XML)
test.df <- xmlToDataFrame("c:/Users/user/Desktop/shares.xml")
test.df
attach(test.df)
mean(as.numeric(Price))
sd (as.numeric(Price)) 
plot(timeStamp,as.numeric(Price))
```

However the resulting plot is not what I expect. It returns the Time stamps on the x axis but the y axis is numbered from 1 - 7. Is there something I should be doing to alter the data set either in R or the XML file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually turn the x-axis data into time objects. Combine your

```
library (XML)
test.df <- xmlToDataFrame("c:/Users/user/Desktop/shares.xml")
test.df
attach(test.df)
mean(as.numeric(Price))
sd (as.numeric(Price))
```

with what I showed you last week in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215783/how-would-i-parse-the-xml-file-in-r-and-carry-out-basic-statistics-analysis-on-th) (and you need `as.character()` as your data probably came in as factors)

```
timeStampParsed <- strptime(as.character(timeStamp), "%H:%M:%OS")
```

before you can plot via

```
plot(timeStampParsed, as.numeric(Price))
```

Likewise for ggplot2: You first need to get your data into a date type.

Lastly, if you want an actual day in there that is different from the imputed default of today, you need to prepend it to the `timeStamp` text as for example in

```
timeStampParsed <- strptime(paste("2010-07-01"), as.character(timeStamp), 
                            "%Y-%m%-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

Comment: Not interested in adding the actual day to the graph. The x-axis is coming out correctly with the timestamps but I am having trouble with the Y axis. The y axis range should go from 0 -> 26 (This should cover all the points I have), but it starts at 15 on the bottom to 16.52 at the top with 25.02, 18.54 etc... in between these values. Since 25.02 is greater than 16.52 I am stuck as to why it is 25.02 is lower on the down on the y axis than 16.52.

Comment: First things first: make sure `summary(test.df)` shows the right data. Also, `attach` is no longer recommended. Do the data transformation directly in the `data.frame`, e.g. `test.df$Price` <- as.numeric(as.character(test.df$Price))`.  It may be as simple as the common 'string as factors' problem which you can circumvent with a global option as well as local ones (though I am unsure about details with the `XML` package I rarely use myself).

Comment: Okay that has sorted the issue. I have always used attach() for accessing variables as instructed, is there a reason for it no longer being recommended. Thanks for the help to date.The code I have now is: library(ggplot2)
library (XML)
test.df <- xmlToDataFrame("c:/Users/user/Desktop/shares.xml")
test.df 
test.df$Price <- as.numeric(as.character(test.df$Price))
test.df$timeStamp <- as.character(as.character(test.df$timeStamp), "%H:%M:%OS")
summary (test.df)
mean(test.df$Price)
sd (test.df$Price)
qplot(timeStamp,Price,data=test.df,geom="point", scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10,26)))

Answer (score -1):

try [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) package from hadley – it´s hilarious.

melt your date with id date and then plot with qplot:

```
test = melt(test.df,id="timestamps")
qplot(timestamp,yvalue,data=test.df,geom="line")
```

etc.

HTH

EDIT:

To influence the scale use:

```
qplot(...) +  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.25,0.25))
```

Also make sure to check ggplot2 documentation (you´ll find it in the link above) – it simply two-steps every other R documentation on plotting out there.

Comment: This suggestion got a nicer graph than the one the original code I was using was producing. However, the price on the y axis are still not right. The Price points go from 15 on the bottom to 16.52 at the top with 25.02, 18.54 etc... in between. This throws out a nonsensical (but I must admit visually pleasing) graph.

Comment: Made the change but the graph is still the same. Here is the line of code I have:
    qplot(timeStamp,Price,data=test.df,geom="point",scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.25,0.25)))

Comment: Dirk is right, you need to format your timestamp. try as.Date() respectively its documentation. I am not sure how to handle this particular timestamp, because the frequency appears to be somewhat higher than what I am used to. In order to suggest a function, it would be helpful to know what the scale actually is. My limits for the y scale where of course just exemplary.